# How can I change the font in the advanced editor in sas?

Tags: fonts, sas

A colleague of mine found a way to do this a long time ago and can't remember how he did it. All the usual colour highlighting is applied when viewing sas code - however, it is displayed in Comic Sans MS (yes, really) rather than the usual SAS Monospace.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the SAS Display Manager system, first make an "Enhanced Editor" window "active".  Then use the "Tools -> Options -> Enhanced Editor...". Click the "Appearance" tab and make whatever changes you want.  Click "OK" and you're done.

You may also need to check the "Save settings on exit" checkbox on the "General" tab on "Tools -> Options -> Preferences..."; I have that checked myself.